# Latex hyperlinks with tooltip or alt text

Tags: graphics, overleaf, links, markdown

I am trying to figure out a way to add tooltips or alternate text to my images and hyperlinks. I use a converter to convert markdown documents to latex so What I need is the following:

This would be a link in my markdown document with an alt text:

```
My favorite search engine is [Duck Duck Go](https://duckduckgo.com "The best search engine for privacy").
```

My favorite search engine is [Duck Duck Go](https://duckduckgo.com).

You can hover the mouse over the link to get the alt text.

Similarly for images:

```
![The San Juan Mountains are beautiful!](/assets/images/san-juan-mountains.jpg "San Juan Mountains")
```

[image: The San Juan Mountains are beautiful!]

Here it works with markdown, hovering mouse over the missing image gives the image title and because the image is not available it gives the alt text.

I tried a similar approach in overleaf:

```
href{https://duckduckgo.com "The best search engine for privacy"}{Duck Duck Go}
```

but compiled it gives mea link with the text added in it: https://duckduckgo.com%20%22the%20best%20search%20engine%20for%20privacy%22/

For images I tried:

```
Nice picture of the polar light, in png.
\begin{figure}[!ht]\centering\captionsetup{justification=centering}\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{img/Polarlight.png}\caption{Aurora Borealis}\end{figure}
```

compiled in overleaf I do get:

Nice picture of the polar light, in png.

justification=centering[width=0.5]img/Polarlight.png

Figure 1.1: Aurora Borealis

So here the text and title are ok, but when an image is not available I would like to omit the justification=centering[width=0.5]img/Polarlight.png part

How can I achieve such a thing within latex?

Comment: "You can hover the mouse over the link to get the alt text." you can but that is a native feature of html, getting a similar feature in a pdf file requires javascript or other extensions and whether or not it works is highly dependent on which pdf reader you use, so independent of how to get that kind of markup into latex it may or may not work.  Your issue with the link text is easier, use `\hyperref{http:some/url}{the link text here}`  and to test if an image is available you can use `\IfFileExists{image.png}{do something withthe image}{do something without the image}`

Comment: Thanks @DavidCarlisle, that's good help. But that would mean I need to add \IfFileExist before every image, isn't there a better way that always uses the IfFileExist logic???

Comment: @DavidCarlisle `Javascript` or other extensions are not required to make an alt text appearing in a tooltip when hovering the mouse over a link: with the Evince PDF reader on GNU/Linux, with a minimal document containing `hyperref` and `\href{https://duckduckgo.com}{Duck Duck Go}`, a tooltip displaying `https://duckduckgo.com` appears when I hover the mouse over the link. OK, other PDF readers don't offer this feature, but I suppose they will sooner or later. So LaTeX should get ready for it! :)